# Show that $\int_0^1 \phi^2(x)dx$ does not exist where $\phi(x)=x^{x-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, integral-equations

iI am currently studying integral equations from the book "Integral Equations" by Harry Hochstadt. In its second exercise (page $42$) it is asked to (Q.No $2$) show that $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \phi^2(x)dx$ does not exist where $\phi(x)=x^{x-1}$

I was unable to solve the problem, What I done so far is:

I think the integral is improper as at $0$ it has a singularity .

So I considered $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \phi^2(x)dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \displaystyle \int_{\epsilon}^1x^{2x-2}dx$ and I have to show this diverges.

But I can not proceed further. I think I have to somehow use the fact $x\ge \epsilon$ in the above integral since $x$ is running from $\epsilon$ to $1$.

Can I proceed with my idea from here? It will be very helpful for me if anyone suggest how should I complete the problem.

Thnx in advance.

**EDIT:**

I tried to plot the graph in [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/). It lokks like the following.

[image]

So the area under the curve within $0$ and $1$ is likely to be infinity but still I can not prove it.

And the answer posted seems to have some problem. I appologise if I am missing something.Please correct me.

Again thnx in advance. It will be very helpful if I get some suugestion to solve it.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.I will surely keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
For $x\le 1$ and $b\ge a$ we have $x^a \le x^b$. Use this estimate with $a = -2$ and $b=2x-2$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. So in this way $\int_0^1\phi^2(x)dx>\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^2}dx$ which divergs. Am I right?

Comment: Wait a minute..If $x=\frac12,b=2,a=1$ then $\frac14$ is not greater than $\frac12$. Is this violating the inequality?Or I am making something silly mistake?